# How to destroy/reset a session with a Form Button in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to destroy/reset my session so it cleans the **Logs** div I created when I press on the Reset Button in my Form. I have assigned a method to my button (**btnReset**) from a .js file that clears the entire page. Now I just want to make so that it just clears the **Logs** div where all my calculations are stored at. I have no idea what to do.

Any help would be super much appreciated. SESSIONS is still very new to me so I'm trying my best to understand it. If anyone can explain to me how to properly clear the **Logs** div after the Reset button has pressed to destroy/reset my session, that would be very much appreciated!

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['results'])) {
    $_SESSION["results"] = [];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Calculator++ with PHP">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Calculator ++ | Calculator</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="Images/favicon-32x32.png">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Style.css">

    <!-- PHP Files -->
    <?php include 'PHP/Calculation.php';?>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Selection for Calculator & Converter -->
    <div class="selection">
        <div class="titleSelect">Options</div>
            <a class="btn-selection" href="Index.php">Calculator</a>
            <a class="btn-selection" href="Converter.php">Converter</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Calculator Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="result">
            <!-- Prints the result -->
            <div class="result"><?php echo $Result; ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class="calculator">
            <form action="Index.php" method="POST">
                <ul>
                    <!-- First number -->
                    <li>
                        <label for="numberOne"><strong>Number one:</strong></label>
                        <input class="inputNumbers" type="number" name="numberOne" placeholder="Enter a number">
                    </li>

                    <!-- Operation -->
                    <li>
                        <label for="operation"><strong>Operation:</strong></label>
                        <select class="inputNumbers" name="operation" id="operator-list">
                            <option value="+">+</option>
                            <option value="-">-</option>
                            <option value="x">x</option>
                            <option value="/">/</option>
                            <option value="sqrt">^</option>
                            <option value="pow">√</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Second number -->
                    <li id="second-input">
                        <label for="numberTwo"><strong>Number two:</strong></label>
                        <input class="inputNumbers" type="number" name="numberTwo" placeholder="Enter a number">
                    </li>

                    <!-- Decimal Slider -->
                    <li>
                        <label><strong>Decimal: </strong><span id="value_slider"></span></label>
                        <input type="range" name="slidebar" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider" class="slider_style input">
                    </li>

                    <!-- Calculate & Reset button -->
                    <li>
                        <input class="btn-calculate" type="submit" name="btnCalculate" value="Calculate">
                        <button class="btn-reset" type="reset" name="resetForm" onclick="btnReset();" value="resetButton">Reset</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Logs -->
        <div class="logs-container">
            <div class="logs-title">Logs</div>
                <div class="logs">
                    <?php echo implode("<br>",$_SESSION["results"]); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/HideSecondInput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Reset.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Calculation.php**

```
<?php

$Result = 0;

if (isset ($_POST['btnCalculate']) ) {

    $numberOne = $_POST['numberOne'];
    $operation = $_POST['operation'];
    $numberTwo = $_POST['numberTwo'];

    if ($operation == '+') {
        $Result = ((int)$numberOne + (int)$numberTwo);
        $_SESSION["results"][]="$numberOne + $numberTwo = $Result";
    }
    
    else if ($operation == '-') {
        $Result = ((int)$numberOne - (int)$numberTwo);
        $_SESSION["results"][]="$numberOne - $numberTwo = $Result";
    } 
    
    else if ($operation == 'x') {
        $Result = ((int)$numberOne * (int)$numberTwo);
        $_SESSION["results"][]="$numberOne * $numberTwo = $Result";
    }

    else if ($operation == '/') {
        if ($numberOne and $numberTwo > 0)
        {
            $Result = $numberOne / $numberTwo;
            $_SESSION["results"][]="$numberOne / $numberTwo = $Result";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Cannot divide by 0');</script>";
        }
    }
       
    else if ($operation == 'sqrt') {
        $Result = sqrt($numberOne);
        $_SESSION["results"][]="sqrt($numberOne) = $Result";
    }

    else if ($operation == 'pow') {
        if ($numberOne and $numberTwo > 0)
        {
            $Result = pow($numberOne, $numberTwo);
            $_SESSION["results"][]="pow($numberOne, $numberTwo) = $Result";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Please enter a number in both fields');</script>";
        }
    }   

    else $Result = 'Unknown';
}
?>
```

**Reset.js**

```
//Resets the entire page when reset button is pressed
function btnReset() {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you basically need to adjust your code in the following way:

- btnReset should send specific flag for session to be destoryed
- btnReset should wait for the request to finish, then do the redirect.
- on PHP, you should check for the flag, and if found, delete the session.

  ```
    function btnReset(event) {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", '/index.php?reset=true', true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
  ```

and In PHP (calucations.php):

```
if(@$_GET['reset'] == true) {
    $_SESSION["results"] = [];
    session_destroy();
}
```

of course, this is simple way to do it, you should consider using jQuery https://jquery.com/ which would help you with the AJAX request, and also instead of doing a redirect, you can simple delete the content of the div containing the logs.

Note some typos in your code, file was called "Index.php" it should be case sensitive, so always call it: index.php